# Anime about a ghost girl that is some kind of urban myth who shows up and helps people

Tags: story-identification, anime, horror, ghost

I don't really remember much, but it is called something "bigaboo phantom". It is an older supernatural/horror anime from the 1990s and recently got a reboot or something in the end of the 2010s.

The ghost girl wore some dark coat and had a big cylinder like hat. In one episode she shows up and saves a high school boy from one of his girl classmates, who turned into a monster.

I don't remember anything else, just that the opening had some lines like "face yourself" or "see inside yourself".

Comment: "*bigaboo phantom*" +1 for effort haha

Answer (score 12, accepted):

***[Boogiepop Phantom](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0324700/)*** (2000)...?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boogiepop_Phantom):

> *Boogiepop Phantom* (Japanese: ブギーポップは笑わない Boogiepop Phantom, Hepburn: *Bugīpoppu wa Warawanai*, lit. "Boogiepop Doesn't Laugh") is an anime television series animated by Madhouse, based on the *Boogiepop* light novel series by Kouhei Kadono. The series is directed by Takashi Watanabe, from a screenplay by Sadayuki Murai, with original character designs by the light novel's illustrator Kouji Ogata, and sound direction by Yota Tsuruoka. Chronologically, the story follows immediately after the events of the series's first volume, *Boogiepop and Others*, while also making references to the prequel sixth volume, *Boogiepop at Dawn*.

> **The story takes place in an unnamed Japanese city, a month after a pillar of light appeared in the night sky and five years after a string of serial killings.** Boogiepop Phantom follows an ensemble cast of characters, mostly high school students, who are witnesses to the incident and its consequences. At the time of the series, **high school students have started to disappear again and the blame is placed on Boogiepop, an urban legend who is said to be the personification of Death.**